# How to modify regex with occurances limits

Tags: regex, string, anagram

I have following regex:

```
^(?!.*([xampl]).*\1)(?!(.*e){3})[example]*$
```

and it works like this:

- it matches all strings containing letters 'x', 'a', 'm', 'p', 'l' (characters occurs only once or not at all)
- it matches all strings in which letter 'e' accurs less than twice

This expression matches following strings:

- example, ample, lap, max, map, plea etc.

I want to modify this expression, so it could match exactly the same strings plus one additional 'wildcard' (one letter a-z).

New expression should match following strings:
- laps, maps, rap, gap etc.

Is it possible?

Comment: Not sure to understand your requirements. Do you only need to specify that one and only one character of a match is not in `[example]` character class?

Comment: Its like scrabble: you have tiles [e, x, a, m, p, l, e] and one blank tile, which you can use instead of any other letter. I need regex that match all possible combinations in this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just adding `[a-z][example]*` before end of string should work. That way you still ensure all letters from your given word are used only once, still restrict the allowed letters to `example`, except for the added wildchar `[a-z]`.

Pattern becomes:

```
^(?!.*([xampl]).*\1)(?!(?:[^e\n]*e){3})[example]*[a-z][example]*$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZFzYPA/1)

Comment: I tried it before but did it wrong. Now it works great. Thank you :)